# Build LL(1) parsing table for grammar S -> iSeS | iS | a

Tags: formal-grammars, parsers

**Task**

1. Bulid parsing table for grammar `S -> iSeS | iS | a`
2. Resolve conflicts in this table and simulate parser work for word `iiaea`

**Problem**

I know how to make a parsing table for unambiguous grammar, and how to simulate parser. However this grammar is an example of **dangling else problem**.

**What I tried**

I was tought that I should remove left recursion and left factoring. Then make a table using first and follow. Whatever I tried I got two grammar expressions in the same row of table. Please provide me some hint what to do in this situation.

[image]

After left factorization

```
S ->  iSS' |a
S'-> e S | ε
```

[image]

Because we will never use `S' ->  ε` (there are no other values which can give us `e` in the `Table` except `Table[S'][e]` ) we can remove this production from parsing table.

**Final solution**

[image]

Comment: Where in that chart is shown your left factoring?

Comment: I updated my left factorization try.

Comment: That's not a correct left-factoring. The longest left factor is $iS$, not $i$; as you can see, in your attempt you have simply created a new non-terminal in need of left-factoring.

Comment: Still not right. Notice how $FIRST(S)$ suddenly includes $e$ and $\epsilon$? Try to be a bit more systematic. I'm going away now...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually you will end up with having to choose  between $S'\to\epsilon$ and $S'\to eS$.

The grammar says that's a conflict.  But can't we deduce which is correct? What if we choose $S\to\epsilon$? Will we ever be able to match the `e`?

Comment: I updated answer.